# Is a frequently triggered CRON Azure web job triggered a second time when it runs longer than the configured frequency

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

Let's assume a job triggerd via CRON every five minutes. For some reason, one execution at 10:00 lasts significantly longer, e.g. 8 minutes. Is a second instance triggered at 10:05?

If yes, what's the right strategy to make sure the job is running as singleton and never twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test it myself yet but from the [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-background-jobs/#_schedule-driven-triggers) I could found that statement

> If you use a schedule-driven task that must run as a single instance,
>   be aware of the following:
>
> - If the compute instance that is running the scheduler (such as a
>     virtual machine using Windows scheduled tasks) is scaled, you will
>     have multiple instances of the scheduler running. These could start
>     multiple instances of the task.
> - If tasks **run for longer** than the
>     period between scheduler events, the scheduler **may start another**
>     **instance** of the task **while** the **previous** one **is still running.**

The possible solution is also mentioned in the docs in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-background-jobs/#_scaling-and-performance-considerations) section

> By default, WebJobs scale with their associated Azure Web Apps
>   instance. However, if you want a WebJob to run as only a single
>   instance, you can create a `Settings.job` file that contains the JSON
>   data `{ "is_singleton": true }`. This forces Azure to only run one
>   instance of the WebJob, even if there are multiple instances of the
>   associated web app. This can be a useful technique for scheduled jobs
>   that must run as only a single instance.

and [that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-background-jobs/#_considerations) section

> By default, WebJobs scale with the web app. However, you can configure
>   jobs to run on single instance by setting the `is_singleton`
>   configuration property to `true`. Single instance WebJobs are useful for
>   tasks that you do not want to scale or run as simultaneous multiple
>   instances, such as reindexing, data analysis, and similar tasks.